# what is the best practice when saving logs in various OSs?

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x, logging

So I'm making a script in python and want it to save logs to a file. I'm using the standard logging module. currently the logs being saved in the script's folder but I don't think that is the right way to do that.

My next step is making my script installable from PyPI, Hence the question. what is the best places to save my script logs in all the major OSs (Mac, link, windows)

Comment: who is supposed to read the logs?

Comment: the user if he wanted to debug himself, or me if there is a problem with it (if the user provide it of course)

Comment: Well common practice is to install log files in /var/log for package managed applications or /usr/local/<app-name>/logs for locally compiled applications

Answer (score 0):

You can save all your logs to /logs or any path of your machine by just specifying the correct setting for standard logging module.

So, basically you can define 'handlers' which says where to put the logs and 'loggers' that will use those handlers to write logs.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file1': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/logs/file1.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'file2': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/logs/file2.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file1'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'logger1': {
            'handlers': ['file1'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'logger2': {
            'handlers': ['file2'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },

          'django.request': {
             'handlers': [file1, file2],
             'level': 'ERROR',
             'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Now, you can use these loggers in your script as below:

```
import logging
info_logger = logging.getLogger(logger1)
error_logger = logging.getLogger(logger2)
```

Comment: yes I know that, I just wanna know the "standard" path\way to save the logs.

Comment: I guess putting logs to root level directory will be fair enough.

Comment: If these logs are suppose to consumed by some external users then you can write a custom scripts to push these logs to Cloudwatch, KIbana or any such services for better categorisation, indexing and readability.

Comment: Never just put files in the root directory of the file system. The directory structure within any *NIX based system is structured the way it is for a reason.